# Angular-Google-Charts, How to fire select event from code?

Tags: angular, google-visualization

How to fire `on-select` when `on-ready` `readyHandler()` is fired from javascript file.

```html
`  <div google-chart 
     chart="$acCtrl.chartData2"
     agc-on-select="onChartItemSelected(selectedItem)" 
     agc-on-ready="readyHandler(chartWrapper)"
     style="height:300px; width:800px;">
 </div>`
```

Comment: `  <div google-chart 
     chart="$acCtrl.chartData2"
     agc-on-select="onChartItemSelected(selectedItem)" 
     agc-on-ready="readyHandler(chartWrapper)"
     style="height:300px; width:800px;">
 </div>`

Comment: seems like you would just call `onChartItemSelected` from within `readyHandler`...?